# Angular2 async testing issue with setTimeout

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

I am using Angular2.0.1 and was trying to write unit tests around an angular component with some async tasks. A fairly common thing to do, I'd say. Even their latest testing examples include these kind of async tests (see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html)).

My own test would never be successful, though, always failing with the message

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Long story short, it took me hours to pinpoint the actual source of problem.
I am using the library angular2-moment and there I was using a pipe called amTimeAgo. This pipe contains a window.setTimeout(...), which is never removed.
If I removed the amTimeAgo pipe, the tests succeed, otherwise they fail.

Here's some very bare bones code to reproduce the issue:

testcomponent.html:

```
{{someDate | amTimeAgo}}
```

testcomponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "testcomponent.html",
    providers: [],
})
export class TestComponent{
    someDate = moment();

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

testmodule.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from "@angular/core";
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment';
import { TestComponent } from './testcomponent';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MomentModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestComponent,
    ]
})
export class TestModule {
}
```

testcomponent.spec.ts:

```
import { async, TestBed, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { TestComponent } from './testcomponent';
import { TestModule } from './testmodule';

let component: TestComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

function createComponent() {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    return Promise.resolve();
}

describe("TestComponent", () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                TestModule],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should load the TestComponent', async(() => {
        createComponent().then(() => {
            expect(component).not.toBe(null);            
        });
    }));

});
```

Does anyone have an idea how to successfully test this? Can I somehow kill all the "left-over" timeouts in an afterEach? Or can I somehow reset the zones the async code runs in to get rid of this issue?

Has anybody else run into this or know how to successfully test this? Any hints would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
After @peeskillet hinted at a solution using `fixture.destroy()`, I went off and tried this in my actual tests (the examples here are just the minimum code required to reproduce the issue). The actual tests contain nested promises, otherwise I wouldn't have required the `async` and `detectChanges` approach.

While the destroy suggestion is great and helps with the problem in the simple tests, my actual tests contain the following statement to ensure that the nested promises are properly resolved:

```
it('should check values after nested promises resolved', async(() => {
    createComponent().then(() => {
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            component.selectedToolAssemblyId = "2ABC100035";

            expect(component.selectedToolAssembly).toBeDefined();
            expect(component.selectedToolAssembly.id).toBe("2ABC100035");

            fixture.destroy();
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
}));
```

The problem is that, with the amTimeAgo pipe in the page, the `fixture.whenStable()` promise is never resolved, so my assertion code is never executed and the test still fails with the same timeout.

So even though the destroy suggestion works on the given simplified tests, it does not enable me to fix the actual tests.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For reference:** [here is the problem pipe in question](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/blob/1.0.0-beta.3/src/TimeAgoPipe.ts)

I think the problem is that the component never gets destroyed in the `async` zone while there are pending async tasks, in this case the pipe's. So the pipe's `ngOnDestroy` (which removes the timeout) never gets called, and timeout is left hanging, which leaves the zone waiting.

There are a couple things that will make it work:

1. I don't know what else you have in your component, but just from what you are showing, the test doesn't *need* to be using `async`. The only reason it does is because you are returning a promise from your `createComponent` method. If you forget the promise (or just *call* the method *without thening*) then the test will be synchonous and no need for `async`. The component gets destroyed after the test finishes. The test passes.
2. This is the better solution though: Simply *destroy the component yourself!*

   ```
    fixture.destroy();
   ```

   Everyone's happy!

I tested both of these solutions, and they both work.

---

#### UPDATE

So the agreed upon solution for this particular case is to just mock the pipe. The pipe doesn't affect any of the component's behavior, so we shouldn't really care what it does, as it's only for display. The pipe itself is already tested by the author of the library, so there's no need for us to need to test its behavior within our component.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'amTimeAgo'
})
class MockTimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: Date) {
    return date.toString();
  }
}
```

Then just take out the `MomentModule` from the `TestBed` configuration, and add the `MockTimeAgoPipe` to the `declarations`

Comment: Hey @peeskillet, thanks for the help. See my update on the question. Quick recap: this resolves the simple test, but my actual async tests still present with the same timeout issue.

Comment: Where are you calling `destroy()`? It needs to be called in the the `whenStable` callback

Comment: I have just updated the code in the question, sorry. The problem is that the destroy is never executed because the whenStable promise is never resolved.

Comment: I'll play around with it a little bit later. I can see whenStable not working as there are still tasks. Maybe we will need some kind of work around without whenStable

Comment: One work around would be to just create a mock pipe for this test.

Comment: Honestly, if I were in this situation, I would just mock the pipe. The pipe doesn't affect any of the component's behavior. It's only for display. You're not really trying to test that the pipe works, that is already done by the library. So just mock it.

Comment: You are completely right. Pretty short-sighted of me not to come up with that myself. Want to update your answer with this as a third point and I'll accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125000/discussion-between-ben-and-peeskillet).